# Пара вопросов о xml.

Tags: xml

В чём вообще смысл xml?
Просто хранить информацию?
Тогда, почему нельзя использовать простой "текстовик"?

И ещё, в xml тэги можно самому придумывать, или есть заранее определённые?

Comment: Почитайте про SOAP и WSDL (формат и применение) - понятнее будет хотя бы одно назначение. А вообще, это закономерно, что не понимаете. Потому что опыта применения у вас элементарно нет.
А вот когда будет у вас задание написать оболочку для некоторого клиента, который через SOAP через WebServices API будет запихивать данные, скажем, в LDAP - вот тогда поймете, чем удобен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML позволяет удобно работать с информацией, так как она помечается тегами.

`<boy>
    <name>Вася</name>
    <age>15</age>
</boy>`

Теги можно делать свои. Но есть и заранее определенные. Хотя точнее будет - общепринятые. Например в RSS.

Answer (score 1):

> XML разрабатывался как язык с простым формальным синтаксисом, удобный для создания и обработки документов программами и одновременно удобный для чтения и создания документов человеком, с подчёркиванием нацеленности на использование в Интернете. Язык называется расширяемым, поскольку он не фиксирует разметку, используемую в документах: разработчик волен создать разметку в соответствии с потребностями к конкретной области, будучи ограниченным лишь синтаксическими правилами языка.

[Из википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)